# How to deal with error "Couldn't find Model with id=0"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, null

Abstracting from my actual database, I have Model1 and Model2 and Model1 has_and_belongs_to_many Model2 and Model2 has_and_belongs_to_many Model1.  In a sign-up page, I have the following:

```
= f.hidden_field :model2_ids
```

But when doing a sign-up where there is no existing model2's in the database, I get the following error:

```
"Couldn't find Model2 with id=0"
```

In the params you can see:

```
"model2_ids"=>"[]",
```

I suppose this evaluates to NULL, which is why I am getting the error I am.  How can I get around this?

Update:

By setting a conditional in the view, I can avoid this problem with a signup where there is no existing model2's or otherwise is no model2_ids being set.  The model2_ids are being set in the controller through an invitation model, and in some signup cases there is an invitation, where the invitation model is specifying a model2.  In an example case, I see in the params:

```
 "model2_ids"=>"[1]",
```

However, I get the same error and this output from the server logs:

```
  Invitation Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."token" = '80c98940448829e7edc623f9886e6930434e245c' LIMIT 1
  Model2 Load (51.8ms)  SELECT "model2s".* FROM "model2s" WHERE "model2s"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 222ms

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Listing with id=0):
  app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb:12:in `create'
```

What is causing this?

Comment: Can you post the model code you used to create the associations?

Comment: Where you are redirecting the user after success login?

Answer (score 1):

Here in controller you can check in controller but it will be like 
 if your params look like

```
params[model_ids] = "" so query will be   if  params[model_ids] == ""
```

or if your params look like \

```
params[model_ids] = [] so query will be   if  params[model_ids] == []
```

and if your params look like

```
params[model_ids] = [""] so query will be   if  params[model_ids] == [""]
```

now in controller you can give any condition or use exception handling to handle this run time error

Answer (score 0):

Object of Model1 is not yet saved into the database then how can you get the Model2 objects that belongs to Model1.

If you are building the form for user

```
<% form_for @user do |f|%>
<% end %>
```

Then you may need a condition something like below

```
unless @user.new_record?
  <%= f.hidden_field :model2_ids %>
end
```